# How to make page reload on esc only when specific class is active

Tags: forms, submit, reload, keyup

The below javascript function works and reloads the page when clicking esc, however I only want it to reload the page when a certain class is active. Basically its a popup that displays after you submit a form. I only want the escape function to refresh page when that popup is visible.

```
  [ Close notification window when clicking the esc keyboard button ]*/
 $(document).keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.which == '27') {
     // reload page on submit
    window.location.href="submit.html";
    //remove popup on submit
    $('.cd-popup-submit').removeClass('is-visible-submit');
     $('.btn-hide-validate-submit').remove();
   }
 });
```